# Convert blob string to image in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, blob

There is an object which contains as a field an image saved as string.

It looks like this

```
myObj = {
  ...
  image: blob:http://localhost:3000/304dbb9b-6465-4dc8-8b2c-5a25fae7e452
};
```

how can this be converted and shown as image?

I need to save it in this form:

```
const row = [
      { label: 'NAME', value: `${myObj.name}` },
      { label: 'IMAGE', value: `${myObj.image}` },
    ];
```

which is mapped and some cells are populated with the data:

```
<table>  
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      {row.map(item => (
        <Cell
          key={row.indexOf(item)}
          label={item.label}
          value={item.value}
        />
      ))}
    </tr>    
</table>
```

How I tried: on the line

```
{ label: 'IMAGE', value: `${myObj.image}` },
```

if it is let like that it will print on the screen the string value.

I tried also instead of ``` value: ``${myObj.image} ``` to put `value: <img alt="" src={myObj.image} />` but in this case nothing is shown

Answer (score 1):

You should use URL.createObjectURL

```
<img src={URL.createObjectURL(myObj.image)} alt=""/>
```